# Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, constructor

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Class1 class = new Class1(30,a);

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

     public int a = 0;


    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a += 1;
    }
 }
```

I want to use the variable 'a' in my calss  but i cant get "move" it over to my class via the constructor i'm using.
The error message i recive is :

Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.

I know it's a basic problem but help is appreciated

```
 class Class1
  {


    private   int r;
    private   int x;

    public Construct(int p, int c)
    {
        this.r = p;
        this.x = c;
    }

  }
```

Comment: It errors on the `Class1 class = new Class1(30,a);` line. What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with class? And don't use a keyword as a varable name (it shouldn't compile).

Comment: I'm going to make a ball follow a parable curve, and i was thinking to put 'a' as the time and my x-cordinate and use it to create a equation to calculate y-cordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the initialization of `class1` into a constructor:

```
class Form1 {
    int a = 0;

    Class1 obj1;

    public Form1() {
        obj1 = new Class1(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate the reason why? Might be useful for OP. (Or point out what he is doing wrong)

Comment: I'm not very sure about the reason behind restriction, except to avoid some unintuitive initialisation behaviour.

Comment: One instance field cannot be used to initialize another instance field. `a` might not have been initialized before `class` or vice-versa.

Comment: @Steve There's no practical reason why the compiler couldn't enforce an ordering on field initialisers - the Java one does, and code analogous to the OP's is valid, if not necessarily a good idea. So the question is why the C# compiler *won't*. Saying "you can't, because the spec says you can't" is more or less a tautology. It isn't very informative, since it's obvious from the fact that, well, you can't do whatever it is.

Comment: I actually couldn't find an explanation of *why* you can't for my answer below... I didn't have much time to slog through the spec though. I wish I did, as I'm curious about this too, and actually just attempted to do this very thing yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a field that depends on another field of the class.

From the [C# Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) 10.5.5:

> Field declarations may include variable-initializers. For static
>   fields, variable initializers correspond to assignment statements that
>   are executed during class initialization. For instance fields,
>   variable initializers correspond to assignment statements that are
>   executed when an instance of the class is created.

and

> The default value initialization described in §10.5.4 occurs for all
>   fields, including fields that have variable initializers. Thus, when a
>   class is initialized, all static fields in that class are first
>   initialized to their default values, and then the static field
>   initializers are executed in textual order. Likewise, when an instance
>   of a class is created, all instance fields in that instance are first
>   initialized to their default values, and then the instance field
>   initializers are executed in textual order.

So, in your code, `a` isn't initialized before `class`, although I don't think the compiler cares whether is comes before or after alphabetically. It just doesn't allow you to use one instance variable to initialize another.